# ASP.NET ListBox with min-width and Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I could create an ASP.NET `ListBox` with horizontal scroll bar using the following code

```
<div style="width:160px; overflow-x:auto;">
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1"  runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

But how can I set the `min-width` property to the `ListBox` so that it will not shrink even if there is no item exist. I tried with CSS's `min-width`, but did not get it.

I visited a page [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/HorizontalListBox.aspx) , but I cannot format it in code behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh.. My Goodness !! I used document mode as IE 7 Standards . `min-width` will not work in IE 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the `min-width` CSS property to `100%` like so:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" style="min-width:100%;">
```

Hope this helps.